# how to create less specific class from another class in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a model:

```
class A {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

I want to create a new class like:

```
class B {
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

I don't want to rewrite all attributes in class B, these attributes are already written in A. How to use A to create B.
We can add extra features to class with **extends** but how do we create less specific class? Are there any patterns for this? How should class A or class B be designed to be more polymorphic?

(I want to use class B for inserting into a database, the model class and database table should be same)

Comment: At first, you do already inherit `a` and `b` from the class `A` in your class `B`. There is no need to shadow these two variables in your class `B` by defining another variable with the same name. In the end, for me this doesn´t make much sense, because following just the logic: when `B` inherits from `A`, `B` automaticly represents something that is an `A` but more specific then `A`. So following just pure logic `B` can´t be something less specific then `A`, because it inherits from it and though is more specific then `A`

Comment: This is very poor object oriented design

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you are able to change the classes/implementation but there seem to be multiple solutions. First one would be to have class `A` extend class `B`

```
public class B {
    int a;
    int b;
}

public class A extends B {
    int c;
}
```

but that is not answering your core question (creating less specif class).

Creating a less specific class (or at least something that mimics it) could be done via interfaces and getter/setters, so for example:

```
public class Implementation implements A,B {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public int getA(){return a;}
    public int getB(){return b;}
    public int getC(){return c;}

    ...
}

public interface A {
   int getA();
   int getB();
   int getC();
}

public interface B {
   int getA();
   int getB();
}
```

Comment: I've modified your code a bit, I think there were a few minor mistakes. In the first section I believe you meant A should extend B, but missed the extends tag.

In the second section, you don't need to repeat the `getA();` and `getB();` as they would have been implemented in the usage of interface `B`

Final bit, don't think interfaces are the way to go, as they'll still need to write the properties out in their concrete classes. Might be better to do an abstract class instead

Comment: As soon as you "think" there are a few mistakes, it's better to ask for clarification / confirmation before making your own edits. Your comment is great, that should get good feedback if the OP responds. But for now I've voted to reject your edit.

Comment: Sure thing, was trying to make it clear on how it works and wasn't sure on best practice and now I know. Thanks for the clarifcation

Comment: Understand your feedback and regarding point 1 you are right... forgot the extends the `extends A`. Regarding point 2, I created 2 interfaces so it is either A or B, so that you can have something like `A instanceA = new Implementation()` and `B instanceB = new Implementation()`. For `instanceA` you can call getA, B and C while for `instanceB` you can only call getA and B

Comment: Seems a funny way to do it to me, I see what you are doing, but now you're relying on the developer to program correctly, I still feel safer if you don't allow them access to methods they shouldn't have. They could cast it to an Implementation and use either set of methods...

Answer (score 0):

There should be an "IS A" relation between parent and derived classes.

I.e. the derived class (B) should also be an instance of it's parent class (A).

If you remove something from B it can't be A anymore.
Therefore it should not be possible.

Answer (score -3):

I guess you need a design technique like composition.

**Explanation :** If you want use class `B` in class `A`, you can use `B b = new B();` in your class `A` ! this is composition.
also you can implement interfaces instead of class which provides you multiple inheritance.
here in syntax : 
`class A implements interface1, interface2`

Comment: this answer is one of the possible ways to fix this issue, why down votes are still here ?

Comment: Because they're linking to an external site without a through explanation here. Maybe if they had expanded on the answer, they might of got more upvotes. In its current state, it should have been a comment

Comment: @Draken I'm agree with you. i'll try to add more info to my answer ,then see what happens..

Comment: please flag my comment, maybe moderators can fix this problem! because my answer is correct!!!